# View & store loaded before controller's init

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am building Sencha touch 2.1 application.

In my application I have one global variable which keeps reference of my controller class. This reference is used to execute a controller function on load of one of the store but the problem comes when I deploy this on slow remote server and store's load is fired before this global variable gets reference of controller object. To provide this reference before store's load I tried putting initialization logic in controllers init method

```
init : function(){
    bossController = this.getApplication().getController('Boss');
},
```

in init method of controller but view & store are loaded before this init is called and hence I get this error:

```
Cannot call method 'loadMagazines' of undefined
```

This is my on load listener in store:

```
listeners:{
        load: function( me, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){ 
            bossController.loadMagazines(this, records);
        }
}
```

I tried initializing this variable in app.js launch() method instead of controller's init method but that also didn't work.

Please note both approaches works fine when I put my code in local apache and access it using my chrome browser but they doesn't work when I put it on slow remote server.

**EDIT**

This is how application flow happens
 0. All the models, views, stores & controllers are defined in app.js

1. Launch function in app.js add main view to the viewport.
2. Main view creates magazine view and add it to itself.
3. In initialize method of magazine view, store is crated and loaded.
4. In load listener of store, controller is used.

This is my view:

```
Ext.define('myshop.view.MagazinePanel', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
requires : [ 
    'myshop.model.MagazinePage',
    'myshop.store.MagazineStore',
    'Ext.XTemplate',
    'Ext.data.Store'
],
alias : 'widget.magazinepanelview',
xtype : 'magazinepanelview',
config : {
    layout : 'hbox',
    id : 'hc',
    scrollable: 'horizontal',
    directionLock : true,
    masked: {
        xtype: 'loadmask',
        message: 'Loading'
    },
inline: {
        wrap: false
    },
    items : [{
        xtype : 'panel',
        html : ''
    }]
},
initialize: function() {
    var me = this;
    var myStore = Ext.create('myshop.store.MagazineStore');
        myStore.load({
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                me.setMasked(false);
            },
            scope: this
        });
    this.callParent();
}
});
```

and this is the store:

```
Ext.define('myshop.store.MagazineStore',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
           'myshop.model.MagazinePage',
           'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'
       ],
config:{
    storeId : 'ms',
    model:'myshop.model.MagazinePage',
    autoLoad :false,
    pageSize: 30,
    proxy : {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: Properties.PORTAL_SERVICE_BASE_URL+'test/categories/list',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        startParam: false, //to remove param "start" and making it constant
        extraParams: {
            start : 0,
            _type : 'json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'categories.data',
            totalProperty: 'categories.status.totalCount'
        }
    },
    listeners:{
        load: function( me, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){ 
            bossController.loadMagazines(this, records);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Show your view and store code. Maybe the store is loading while the view is defining. In this case controller could be not instantiated.

Comment: Some more code and details added, please check.

Comment: One thing isn't clear. Where you add controller to application? It must be added before launch of application.

Comment: I don't add that manually, I just defined it in app.js like this :                     controllers: ['Boss'],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data should do controller but not view.

```
   Ext.define("myshop.controller.Boss", {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            magazinePanel: '#hc'
        },
        control: {
            magazinePanel: {
                initialize: 'initializeMagazinePanel'
            }
        }
    },

    initializeMagazinePanel: function() {
        var me = this;
        var myStore = Ext.create('myshop.store.MagazineStore', {
            listeners:{
                scope: this,
                load: this.onMagazineStoreLoad
            }
        });
        myStore.load();
    },

    onMagazineStoreLoad: function(me, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
        this.getMagazinePanel().setMasked(false);
        this.loadMagazines(records)
    },

    loadMagazines: function(records) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I did it and things seems to be working fine when I fire "initializeMagazinePanel" defrred by 500ms, because if it is not deferred controller is not ready to listen and event is lost. I wish there could be cleaner way to load controller before this view. BTW, I tried adding controller as dependency to view but it caused stack overflow because of circular dependency.

Comment: You do something wrong. If you add controllers in app's config, all controllers will be loaded by Ext.Loader before the application is launch.

Comment: Thats true, controllers are getting loaded before app is launched but problem is views are loaded before controllers and load listener of view is fired before controller is loaded

Comment: This is wrong. The view could be loaded before controller. It doesn't matter of order in which classes are loading, because they just difining(initialize of view do NOT call, store do NOT loading). So, when all classes are loaded the application calls LAUNCH, where you add view to the Viewport(Cantroller is already loaded). Then view fires 'Initialize' event on which Controller is subscribed(method 'initializeMagazinePanel') and so on. The all steps that I've described must be doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some parts missing in your example code so just a hint/guess. I guess your store has `autoLoad` property to true and get's therefore loaded as soon as it gets initialized. Turn it of and try something like this.

```
init : function(){
    bossController = this.getApplication().getController('Boss'); // bossController where is this var defined? 
    // fire a ready event
    // or
    Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('YourStoreName').load();
}
```

Or provide more information about the store, who loads it, when it is loaded and in which scope.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information, the store has "autoLoad :false" it is created and loaded when view is initialized which means my view gets loaded and initialized before controller is loaded. I will update details in question also.

Comment: @ThinkFloyd
If this all happens at app start you should add the controller into the application controller array ifnot I guess your responsible view is bound to a controller so you should load the other controller within the init method of this controller. Plz give me feedback if this helps.

Comment: I have added this controller in controller array of app and view in view array, but the problem is sometime the views get loaded before controller hence I am getting this issue randomly.

Comment: @ThinkFloyd That should never happens. Only the controller self instantiate it's views. I guess you have a design issue here. You will need to fix this, not only in this controller or you may face more of these problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you put your loadMagazines function in the success callback of an explicit load() function in your controller, and disable autoLoad as @sra suggests?

Something like:

```
//in controller
init: function() {
    myStore.load({
        callback: function(recs, op, success) {
            // do the load magazines thing
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if what I suggested here: [getController() doesn't load file and doesn't fire init and lauch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613014/getcontroller-doesnt-load-file-and-doesnt-fire-init-and-lauch) helps with this too.  You can remove the view and store from app.js and put it in the controller itself.  I think that should make the view and store be defined only after the controller is defined.